# Overwrite css external link

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to overwrite a css style that is placed in the body of my blog. See the picture:

[image]

Through the following code:

```
html,body{
    background:#0a0a0a url(http://static.boo-box.com/campaigns/youtube-music-box-n0210-3110-cpm-bg_20131007/bg_booboxrosbg1280x1024-1.jpg) no-repeat fixed top center !important;
}
```

The background color of the original blog is:
[image]

I've tried to overwrite jquery, css, but nothing worked. Anyone any suggestions?
Below is the code I tried, but none worked.

```
<style>
html,body{
    background:#F1F1F1 !important;
}
</style>

$('body').removeAttr('background');
```

To see the problem online access: [www.obovio.com.br](http://www.obovio.com.br)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The try css instead of attr.  Try:

```
$('html,body').css('background','#F1F1F1');
```

Comment: Just looked at your site, that background is set on #wrapper not the body or html tags.

Comment: Actually, it's set on all three.  Is this a hack to your site, or are you intentionally setting that somewhere?

Comment: Barbara this is precisely the problem. I have a partner that generates advertisement for my blogger, but sometimes it generates an advertisement full body applying it in the "body" and "html" page. I wanted to remove this style of these two elements.

Comment: The #wrapper tag is full width, so to get rid of it you'll need to change html, body, #wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Change your jQuery to:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {

    function removeBG() {
        $('html, body').css('background', '#F1F1F1');
    }

    setTimeout('removeBG()', 1000);
});
```

Comment: Try the newest revision, using setTimeout. Since it is being called from a 3rd party, remove it after it's loaded.